# Snakemake's good way to reuse rules in other rules

Tags: python-3.x, makefile, snakemake

I want to create in a Snakefile a rule that can call other rules.
For example, I want to create a rule `re` that calls `clean` and after, `all`.
Following is the Makefile version of this:

```
.PHONY=all clean re
all: toto.txt

toto.txt:
    touch toto.txt

clean:
    rm toto.txt

re: clean all
```

In this Makefile, `re` leads to a full regeneration of created files.
I searched many ways to do it in Snakemake, and I didn't find a pleasant way to do it.
Here are the results of my researches:

- Calling snakemake in shell section (no way, bad idea)
- DUPLICATE the content of rules in `re` (no way, my real case is too much complicated for this).
- We have access to "rules" parameter in input and output. I didn't find a way to "call" those other rules with it. Any idea?
- We can put `touch("rule.done")` in output of the called rules, and call them in "re" rule. Those files are called Flag files in the doc. Problem, it leaves some files after the rule is finished, so I found that...
- We can put `temp("filename")` in output of the called rules, to say to Snakefile to delete them after he runs.

So with this my snakefile ended up like this:

```
rule all:
    input: toto.txt
    output: temp(touch("all.done"))

rule generate_toto:
    output: toto.txt
    shell: touch toto.txt

rule clean:
    output: temp(touch("clean.done"))
    shell: rm toto.txt

rule re:
    input: "all.done", "clean.done"
```

BUT it is not working because Snakemake launch the rules in this order: 
generate_toto > clean > all
This leads to a timeout because job `all` wait for the toto.txt creation. I didn't find a way to say to Snakemake to just do `clean` BEFORE doing `all`.

Seems like it's a mini problem but it's just an example, not my real case: I want `all` to call a rule who launches a script and I'm not able to do it. Where is my .PHONY? :'(

So to resume:

- How can we call other rules from a rule?
- How can we say to Snakemake to run rules in a specific order (without the obvious workaround on making each rule inter-dependant of the others, which is not SOLID please)?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested but I think you can accomplish calling a rule from another rule by abusing the checkpoint syntax.  Make your clean rule into a checkpoint (or add an intermediate rule that depends on clean).  Next make your input to `re` be a function like:

```
def re_input(wildcards):
    checkpoints.clean.get().output  # force running clean
    return ALL_INPUTS  # may be able to use rules.all.input?
```

The checkpoint forces that rule to run first then you return your normal outputs from all.

For your second question, you can use [priorities](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#priorities) to ensure `clean` runs first.  You still need to have phony touch files to get everything running, but after that clean will run first.